# Raycast2D not detecting Rigidbody2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, raycasting, rigid-bodies

I have a box that fires a 2D raycast forward every few seconds, and want it to detect the player's rigidbody2D. I am able to get the raycast firing (the debug draws it correctly), but for some reason it is not detecting the player's rigidbody2D component.

```
void Shoot()
{
    // convert this object's Rigidbody2D [_rb] rotation to radians
    float rad = _rb.rotation * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
    // use some math I found who-knows-where to make a Vector2 projecting forward
    Vector2 firingAngle = new Vector2(Mathf.Cos(rad), Mathf.Sin(rad));
    // project a 2D raycast from the position of the Rigidbody2D out to [range]
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(_rb.position, firingAngle, range);
    
    if (hit.rigidbody != null)
    {
        // **This part of the code never runs, even if the player is clearly intersecting the raycast.**
        Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, firingAngle*hit.distance, Color.yellow, 1f);
        Debug.Log("Hit");
    } else {
        // **Instead, this part always runs.**
        Debug.DrawRay(this.transform.position, firingAngle*range, Color.white, 1f);
        Debug.Log("Did not hit");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the player have at least one Collider2D attached to it or one of its children?

Comment: I thought it still needed a collider

Comment: @NathanWiles I thought Rigidbody2D was a type of Collider2D that would register with the raycast, especially since the if function checks for hit.rigidbody not hit.collider

Comment: @BugFinder Looks like you're both right, I did indeed still need to put a Collider2D on the player. Problem solved I guess...

Comment: Great, I added an answer for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when doing raycasts against GameObjects with a `Rigidbody` or `Rigidbody2D` component, that there is also a corresponding `Collider` or `Collider2D` component (either on the GameObject itself, or one of its children).

Otherwise, raycasts and collision events won't trigger.

Comment: Now that I've implemented the Collider, I'm getting a NullReferenceException that points at hit.collider
`if (hit.rigidbody != null)
{
    Debug.DrawRay(_rb.position, firingAngle*hit.distance, Color.red);
    hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Damageable>().Damage(dt, damage);
}`

Comment: I would consider that to be a different unrelated problem, but feel free to search for or create a question for that issue as well.